# Kotlin - universal method to check parameters for null

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-null-safety

I'm using `Kotlin` and thought about writing universal method to check if any of passed arguments are `not null`.

Method could be used in `if` statement instead manually checking each argument. And if parameters are not null then compiler should assume that inside `if` statement they are still `not null`. Example below:

```
fun getFoo(): Foo? {
  //return value
}

fun getBar(): Bar? {
  //return value
}

fun execute(foo: Foo, bar: Bar) {
  //do stuff
}
```

This is "traditional" way:

```
val foo = getFoo()
val bar = getBar()
if(foo != null && bar != null) {
  execute(foo, bar)
}
```

And this is what I thought to do:

```
fun isNotNull(vararg params: Any?): Boolean {
  return params.filterNotNull().isNotEmpty()
}

val foo = getFoo()
val bar = getBar()
if(isNotNull(foo, bar)) {
  execute(foo, bar)
}
```

Of course code above is not compiling (`Type mismatch, Required: Foo, Found: Foo?`).

Is there any way to assure compiler that `foo` and `bar` was already checked for `null`? I could use `!!` in each parameter but it's not very elegant solution. Maybe some construction using `contract`?

When using manual check `foo != null && bar != null` then there is not problem because of automatic `smart cast` to `Foo` and `Bar`.

Comment: especially answer with rating 115

Comment: @Eugene it looks very interesting, I will check that! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure why you'd need a custom function for this. The idea behind kotlin null safety is to avoid the need for these methods. A simple case is using `let`:

```
fun m(foo: Foo?) {
  foo?.let {
      // it is not null here
  }
}
```

That said, should the need for such a method arise, there's a new experimental feature called contracts that enables smart casts. You could write a method like so (I haven't tried this myself, read more about it [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew13.html#custom-contracts)

```
fun String?.isNullOrEmpty(): Boolean {
  contract {
    returns(false) implies (this@isNullOrEmpty != null)
  }
  return this == null || isEmpty()
}
```

This is for a `string`, but I guess one could do it for `Any`. I also think this specific method already exists in the stdlib anyway.

Again, it feels to me this is a bit pointless, but at least it's possible. You'll need to enable the experimental features.

Comment: the idea was to use this function in condition check where I have to pass multiple parameters to 3rd party library and all of them should be ```not null```. Doing it manually I have to write 2 or 3 line ```if``` statement where I check every parameter is ```!= null```. I know that I can use ```?.let``` but like I said there is multiple variables to check. I tried to write something using ```contract``` but I don't have any experience with it and I don't really know how to use it in my method.

Comment: What happens if the parameters are null? Will you crash the app with an exception? If so, then just use `!!`. No need to check if they are null. The operator `!!` will do that for you. Going a step further, why even allow null? Just declare your method as not accepting nulls.